If microwave ovens run at 2.4 GHz, what is the long-term effect on living tissue of exposure to this frequency, but with a thousand times less energy?
Very low power electromagnetic waves with a frequency of 2.4 GHz can't cook anything. That's obvious, despite the heating effect such radiation has on water.
However, what if such an object containing water is exposed to this radiation for a long time?
Is there a chance of some further physical effect, however slight?

Some comments removed; please remember that answers belong in answers

Bluetooth is already right in this frequency band. A typical microwave oven is 1000 W. Allowable exposure to Bluetooth energy is limited to 1.6 W/kg. So essentially this exact experiment is being run continuously over the entire developed world.
2.4 GHz is non-ionizing. The only known physical effect is tissue heating. At this level of exposure normal thermoregulation is capable of dissipating the heat and maintaining temperatures within normal physiological temperature fluctuations.
There are some published studies claiming adverse effects. However, to date no such studies have proved reproducible by subsequent independent investigators.
Should reproducible evidence of such adverse effects be substantiated then the IEC will revise its guidelines and tighten the limits (as it has in the past).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The only effect is heating. Microwaves are non-ionizing radiation which means they do not break chemical bonds. Microwaves have an energy of about 10^-5 eV. Ionizing radiation is defined by the FCC to start at 10 eV (molecular bond energies are usually 1-10 eV per bond, and 10 eV corresponds to 124 nm ultraviolet). The EPA definition is that ionizing radiation starts at 33 eV (the ionization energy for a molecule of water). Either way, 10^-5 eV is well under this limit.
Being under the limit doesn't mean that it takes more radiation to be ionizing, it means that it is never ionizing. If the energy of the photons is below this limit, then no amount of exposure will make it ionizing (unless you receive so much that you become so hot that you turn into a fine plasma, but  people do not get vaporized when they turn on their cell phones' Bluetooth or stand next to their 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi router). You can't increase photon energy just by increasing the number of photons.

As long as your body is able to dissipate heat faster than it accumulates it, there are no negative effects whatsoever. For non-ionizing radiation, the test for whether it is harmful is easy: Are you burning or overheating due to radiative heating? Then you're receiving too much radiation. Otherwise it's fine.
Could there be unknown effects? Maybe, but there is no reputable research which shows any negative effects. The slight tissue heating you receive from the 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi or Bluetooth signals from your phone is dwarfed by the amount of tissue heating caused by your muscles holding the phone up.

"it means that it is never ionizing" Not entirely correct. There are effects from n-photon-exitation that utilize virtual exited states and enough energy to break a bond can be harvested from n photons. Is this effect ridiculously small in the average situation, making this comment more of a silly nitpick? Certainly possible.

Ionizing is spelled with a 'z' and not an 's'.

@mcodesmart you're the real-world example of an anectode: should you follow, in an international context, the spelling rules of British (BE) or American english (AE)? The answer: AE. Because if you write "ionizing" (AE) and a brit reads it, he will think "must be american spelling". If you write "ionising" (BE) and a US person reads it, he will say "what a moron, cannot spell 'ionizing' correctly". There is a whole world outside of the US, and a whole bunch of other languages (and spelling). And all are we together in the internet. Welcome to the global world!

@Mayou36 More amusingly, there are significantly more people in the world who speak British English or other dialects that use British spelling than those that use American spelling, which makes the whole thing even more bizarre

"Microwaves are non-ionizing radiation which means they do not break chemical bonds." You break chemical bonds regularly on a stove, in an oven or a toaster, and neither uses ionizing radiation for that.

As already pointed out, to date the only known potential biological effect of microwave oven electromagnetic radiation, which is non-ionizing radiation, is the heating of tissue. There are, as yet, no known long term non thermal effects, though studies continue.
In the U.S. the FDA requires that microwave leakage from ovens cannot exceed 5 mw/cm$^2$ measured 5 cm from the oven surface over the lifetime of the oven, which would be about 0.05 mw/cm$^2$ at a distance 50 cm from the surface. To date, these values are far below that known to cause biological harm.
For background information on the biological hazards of microwave radiation and the rationale behind the microwave oven leakage limits see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0362028X23009407?via%3Dihub
Hope this helps.

"As yet" is shorthand for "We've been studying this for a century and a quarter, and haven't found any effects other than heating".

@Mark Amen to that. I had engineering responsibility for developing a safety standard for microwave ovens in the early 1970's (yeah, I'm that old!). When the ovens first  came out Consumer's reports rated them all "not recommended" because of the "unknown long term effects" of low level microwaves. It's been studied ever since.

@Mark magnetism had been studied for 3000 years before Faraday discovered induction. In the over 40 years old study that Bob_D has referenced there is a section titled "EFFECTS ON THE NERVOUS SYSTEM", these are $\le 10mW/cm^2$ experiments. A cell-phone has around average (not peak) 600mW emission limit, and children hold that stuff to their heads for hours, and fearmongering aside I let you draw your own conclusion if it is a good idea or not to support that. I stand by my comments I made above though beside some real-life experience in the RF/mw field I claim no special expertise in the area.

@hyportnex (et al ) Just to be clear, my purpose in citing the “40 years old study” was to provide the historical basis for the original development of the microwave emissions standards, certainly not that it reflects current knowledge. Also as far as long term effects I’m referring only to microwave ovens, not cell phones which didn’t exist.  I agree with you it is wise to use them caution. The problem with long term effects is, well, it takes a long time for them to occur. Fortunately, based on observations of my grandchildren, the phones are rarely next to their ears.

What I meant was they spend most of their time texting and surfing the web rather than talking on their phones

You misunderstood me. I mentioned the age of the report to point out that already 40+ years ago neurological effects had been reported at $<10mW/cm^2$ level, not necessarily physically measurable effects but neurological effects, the two are not the same, and just because they are difficult to reproduce it does not mean that we ought to dismiss them by saying that nonionizing radiation causes only heating. Electric pulse conduction in nerves is a very complex nonlinear phenomenon and it takes a theory for a phenomenon to be observed... Bluetooth, most wifi are also in $2.4-2.5GHz$.

@hyportnex  OK. But I think you may misunderstand me as well. I am not minimizing the non thermal concerns where applicable. They just  don't appear to be applicable to microwave ovens where we have max 5 mw/cm$^2$ 5 cm from the surface.. Let's just leave it at that.

Exposure in itself may not be harmful / isn't harmful.
If you place a stone gently upon your skull, and leave it there for hours, you are certain to experience no harmful effects from this low-intensity, long-duration exposure of your head to the stone.
If the exposure-event was to be fast but short term, then one will definitely experience adverse effects.
The presence of the stone upon the head, or the 2.4 GHz does not have an accumulative effect as opposed to (for instance) heavy metal contamination in food/water.
